# I can't install FireStore pod in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I can't install FireStore pod in iOS.

> ```
> 1. [!] CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 2 error(s): CDN: trunk URL
>    couldn't be downloaded:
>    https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/3/f/FirebaseFirestoreSwift/0.2/FirebaseFirestoreSwift.podspec.json
>    Response: Timeout was reached CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded:
>    https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/3/f/FirebaseFirestoreSwift/0.3.0/FirebaseFirestoreSwift.podspec.json
>    Response: Timeout was reached
> ```

> and this error too
>
> ```
> Analyzing dependencies [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible
> versions for pod "nanopb":   In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
>     nanopb (= 1.30905.0, ~> 1.30905.0)
>
>   In Podfile:
>     FireStore was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
>       FirebaseFirestore (~> 0.14) was resolved to 0.16.1, which depends on
>         nanopb (~> 0.3.8)
>
> Firebase/Auth was resolved to 6.29.0, which depends on
>       Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.29.0) was resolved to 6.29.0, which depends on
>         FirebaseCore (= 6.9.2) was resolved to 6.9.2, which depends on
>           FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.5.0, which depends on
>             nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
> ```

Comment: could you add a copy of your Podfile?

Comment: pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'OneSignal'
  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod 'SinchRTC'
  pod 'CryptoSwift'
  pod 'InputBarAccessoryView'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'MessageKit'
  pod 'NYTPhotoViewer'
  pod 'ProgressHUD'
  pod 'Reachability'
  pod 'RNCryptor-objc'
  pod 'SoundManager'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'

Answer (score 2):

Running these commands solved it for me:

1. `pod repo remove trunk`
2. `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

I also got this `Response: Timeout was reached` error. The solution for me was to connect to a VPN, using an American server (sitting in Germany).

Answer (score 0):

`pod update` might resolve.

If not, examine the generated `Podfile.lock` to see why FirebaseFirestore is restricted to a very old version.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
pod repo update --verbose
```